# Uploading monthly data into Access from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, recordset

I have an Access database which needs to take monthly updates from an excel spreadsheet.
The spreadsheet has meaningful column headings which don't match the database tables.
In addition, I need to check whether data is to be merged or appended. 
So I want to obtain a dataset from the Spreadsheet which I can loop through and have my code decide what to do with the data.
I could create a temporary table in Access which exactly matches the spreadsheet structure, populate this with DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, do my stuff and then delete it.

Is this the simplest method, or can I do something like:

```
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" _
   & Chr(34) & fromFile & Chr(34) & "].[sheet1]"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
```

This code produces the error: Cannot Update. Database or object is read only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it better to create new table in access
and then first copy all excel data to that table
then everything will work fine and faster

ilan

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ADO, not a DOA recordset. ADO requires that you add a reference (unless you use late binding). Some of the properties and methods of ADO are different from DAO, like there is not .Edit method in ADO.

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Scripts\Test.xls;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";" 

objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("Name"), _
        objRecordset.Fields.Item("Number")
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

This was taken from MS's technet site where you can get more detailed information:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx